# Problem installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dpkg

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop. I tried upgrading to 12.04, but I could not do it all at once due to limited Internet access. I had the previous version of Ubuntu already on my laptop. Once I closed my laptop during the installation process. I forgot to cancel the installation before doing so. Now when I turn on my computer I get a purple screen that says:

```
GNU GRUB version 1.99-12ubuntu5
```

followed by a list of Ubuntu versions to boot and couple of memory test options. All the tests come out fine. When I try to boot one of the options I get a black screen that says:

```
mountall: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib/libply.so.2)
General error mounting filesystems.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and reboot the system
```

When I try `apt-get install` to install whats missing I get:

```
W: Not using locking for read-only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct problem
```

When I try to run that it says

```
dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: read-only file system.
```

I also made an install disk of 12.04 from my girlfriend computer. I then try to boot it off the CD drive. It opens Ubuntu then an error shows up saying that there is a problem with the media I'm trying to install it from. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend downloading the ISO from Ubuntu.com, doing a md5 check before burning the CD. [More on that here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM/), and then doing a reinstall **without** formatting, so that you preserve your data.